# Jbosss fails to start with jdk1.7

Tags: java, jboss, rhel

`Jboss 5.1`  fails to start with `jdk1.7.0_25`, but it starts fine with `jdk1.6`

With `jdk1.7.0_25` , jboss start fails with the following error.

```
JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /home/zaman/jboss/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as

JAVA: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25//bin/java

JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m     -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

CLASSPATH: /home/zaman/jboss/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/bin/run.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25//lib/tools.jar

=========================================================================

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/bootstrap/BaseServerConfig
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.doInit(AbstractServerImpl.java:190)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.init(AbstractServerImpl.java:173)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.init(AbstractServerImpl.java:143)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:218)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.bootstrap.BaseServerConfig
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 6 more
```

`java.io.File`  entry is already there in constructor parameter in profile.xml file as suggested in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21652494

`grep "java.io" ../server/default/conf/bootstrap/profile.xml 
        <constructor><parameter class="java.io.File"><inject bean="BootstrapProfileFactory" property="attachmentStoreRoot" /></parameter></constructor>`

How to fix this issue . We need to use JDK1.7 only.

Comment: Maybe this will fix also your problem http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21652494

Answer (score 3):

jboss eap 5.1 doesn't work with jdk 7. You can either upgrade to 5.2, or update to 5.1.2 and apply a patch.

Sources

https://access.redhat.com/articles/113083#Compat_5

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223228

Comment: I can confirm i tried many times and gave up, just use jdk 6 or upgrade to jboss eap 6.1

Answer (score 0):

It means your Jboss is not supporting the jdk 1.7 ,there are two options to solve this issue ,Read hat already having a patch for solving this issue please refer this link "https://access.redhat.com/support/" else configure the JAVA_HOME with jdk 1.6 either in bash profile or the run.conf in your Jboss this will solve the issue .